# When does a transpiler (like babel) changes ecmascript6 code into ecmascript5 code?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5, transpiler

I am working with babel, maven, `angular 1.5` and `es6`. Came across with the concept of transpilers converting code written in `es6` internally into `es5` code for backward compatibility of browser. 
Would like to know When does a transpiler (like `babel`) changes `ecmascript6` code into `ecmascript5` code ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'when'? It transpiles your code when you tell it to do so.

Comment: I got the answer now.

Comment: FYI: Generally speaking should transpile your javascript files before any request is sent. It would certainly be possible to transpile the code on every http request, but that would be horribly inefficient. But I would definitely recommend to only transpile once and save the transpiled files so that all clients can use them. – Forivin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no sure if I understand your question. If you install babel like this:

```
npm install -g babel-cli
```

You can transpile your code by running:

```
babel script.js --out-file script-compiled.js
```

If you use gulp like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task("default", function () {
    return gulp.src("src/js/*.js")
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
});
```

It would transpile your code and save it into `dist/js`.

If you want you can also define a gulp watch so that your code is transpiled as soon as you save it:

```
var paths = {
  babel: './somedir'
}
gulp.task('babel', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.babel)
  .pipe(babel())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
})
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.babel, ['babel'])
})
```

If you'd run the gulp watch task, it would automatically wait until files change and then transpile them instantly.

---

**Edit (after the the question was clarified)**:

Generally speaking you should transpile your javascript files before any request is sent. It would certainly be possible to transpile the code on every http request, but that would be horribly inefficient. So I would definitely recommend to only transpile once and save the transpiled files so that all clients can use them.

Comment: _Ya I get your point._  I am asking when does it actually gets transpile.
Is the code transpiled and then put on the server by babel or every time a request from client hits the server, the code is transpiled and response is sent back ?

Comment: Generally speaking should transpile your javascript files before any request is sent. It would certainly be possible to transpile the code on every http request, but that would be horribly inefficient. But I would definitely recommend to only transpile once and save the transpiled files so that all clients can use them.

Comment: You may click the check mark next to the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your code on server. it gets converted from es6 to es5.

Comment: could you please let me know which version of babel you are using?

Comment: 6.4.2 is the version.

Comment: and angular 1.5 ?